# how to connect to MySQL on localhost

Tags: mysql

I have wamp installed and have changed the default port (apache) to port 8888.
Now, I can see the landing page when I go to http://localhost:8888/app
But, when I try to connect to my database as follows:

```
function get_db_conn() {
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('bargainalerts_db', $conn);

    if ($db_selected) {
        return $conn;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The conn variable is always null. I can't connect to my database.I imagine it's something to do with the localhost:8888 bit. I tried setting this as the database url but it just times out. I can view the phpmyadmin control panel via the same url as above.

But I just cant get a php connection. Any help would be greatly welcolmed! Thank you.

Comment: First off, "localhost:8888"? Your code shows that it's connected to the default port of 3306, not 8888.

Comment: @Di-0xide - He's talking about the Apache port, not the MySQL port.

Comment: @user542548 - What error is being output? (Also, is the MySQL server actually running? You can use the wamp taskbar utility to check.)

Comment: The Apache port shouldn't really affect what port MySQL connects on - are you sure your username/password combination is correct? (Only thing I can think of...)

Comment: OH! Thanks middaparka. I completely missed that.

Comment: @user542548 - try taking out the mysql_select_db bit and the conditional at the end of the function and just return $conn. See if it is still null. Also keep in mind that echoing a false boolean value (which is what mysql_connect returns on error) will echo nothing, not a "0". Use print_r or var_dump to see the output.

Answer (score 3):

edit `httpd.conf` in Apache on wamp listen on port 80 save open browser type in `localhost:80` with `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Check that your database if started, that you have indeed root as user and an empty password (which I doubt). Check also your MySQL port (3306 by default) and inspect the output of `mysql_error()`

Comment: "Which I doubt" -- for many dev environments I use a blank password. Just throwing that out there. Also, the problem with mysql_error on the mysql_connect call is that it's one of the most vague errors ever to be seen. Usually it says "Unable to connect to blahblahblah (Using password: NO)".

Comment: The doubt is because a lot of installers refuses to let blank passwords of give a warning

Comment: Not necessarily. Mysql's community edition hasn't moaned about blank passwords for many major-revisions.